# How to write a SQL with difrre

Tags: sql

I have three tables.

```
Table A
ID   Date1  Date2

Table B
Date1 name1  

Table C
Date2 name2
```

A's Date1 in Table B and Date12 in Table C.

Now I want:

For each Item in A, if Date2 is not null, display name2, else display name1
is it possible with a simple SQL?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Select C.name2 from TableA A 
join TableC C on A.date2 = C.Date2
union all
Select B.name1 from TableA A
join TableB B on B.Date1 = A.Date1
where date2 is null
```

You won't get ordered results in this one but you can select Id in this and order it by id.